# using SBT for multimodule project?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

How to use SBT to leverage multi module project. I have tried with the sbt-idea plugin but failed. what could be the reason for this

Comment: How did it fail? What happened?

Comment: when I run sbt from the terminal, I got a response saying "multiple modules detected" after that I got struck up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[An integrated SBT + IDEA Scala Development Setup](http://www.decodified.com/scala/2010/10/12/an-integrated-sbt-and-idea-scala-dev-setup.html) helped me.

Comment: I have followed that same link however i have fixed it anyways thanks for the answer !!!

Comment: Note that this guide was written for 0.7.* version of SBT, while current is 0.11.*

Answer (score 4):

Don't know about the IDEA plugin, but personally I took inspiration from the Akka project to create my own multi-module project:

- https://github.com/akka/akka

Hope that's help !

Answer (score 4):

For now there is a very good [sbt tutorial](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.1/docs/index.html) at its homepage. Here is the chapter providing details on [Multi-Projects](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.1/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html) but I recommend to read through all the chapters before this one.