# Share database code between akka sbt-project and scala-play project

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, akka

I would like to make my database code accessible from both my akka project and my scala-play project. I would like to this in a way that when I make a change in the database code and compile, both projects would directly have access to the compiled result.

I think this is possible with sbt but I don't know how. If anyone could provide me with a minimal example, that would be great :).

Comment: I think you want something along the lines of publishing your database code as a library jar to your local Maven repo, and then have sbt pull in that dependency for each project.  I've never done this, though, so you'd have to figure out the implementation for yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [using SBT for multimodule project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308930/using-sbt-for-multimodule-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options here:

If you setup your akka project and scala-play project separately, then you need to setup a third project (maybe using template "min-scala"), and publish that project into a repository. In this new project, you need to set where to publish it, and also define project name, organization and version number clearly. You sbt might like like this

```
name := """my-database-lib"""
organization := "org.my.project"
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
scalaVersion := "2.11.6"
publishTo := Some("Nexus" at "http://nexus.myrepo.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/play-snapshot/")
```

Then you can add this line into your play and akka projects to reference it:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.my.project" %% "my-database-lib" % "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

You need to run `activator publish` on the shared project to get the library uploaded to repository. If you don't have a shared repository, you can skip the `publishTo` configuration and use `activator publishLocal` to publish your shared lib only on your computer.

The second solution is to define all three projects into one build, by putting other projects into a modules folder of one project. You can define multiple projects as modules within one sbt like this:

```
lazy val playProject = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)
.dependsOn(databaseLib).aggregate(databaseLib)

lazy val akkaProject = (project in file("modules/akka"))
.dependsOn(databaseLib)..aggregate(databaseLib)

lazy val databaseLib = (project in file("modules/database"))
```

Then you can use `activator projects` to list all projects, and use `activator "project akkaProject"` to switch root project.

The benefit of the second solution is the code will automatically recompile whenever a change is made in the shared project, but you can not split the code into several repositories and maintan them separately.